# clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-pie'

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile, but I get this error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-pie'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-pie'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-pie'

   compilation of semantic_checks.c failed
   compilation of build_rtds_skeletons.c failed
   compilation of build_c_glue.c failed

gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using a too old clang version.

For me, clang accepts the `-no-pie` option, so I get no error when doing e.g. this:

```
clang -no-pie test.c
```

Use `clang --version` to check which version you are using. Here is what I get:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 8.0.0-3 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Try to install a newer clang version somehow. One way to do that may be to do something like `sudo apt install clang-8`.